# Decimal values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, decimal

I'm trying to upload CSV file into a table, and i'm have some issues. The CSV file have many decimal values and i don't know exactly how to define the column data type.

I defined:

```
column_a decimal(20,15)
```

I inserted:

```
0.277819139999999
```

The following value is what i see in the table:

```
0.229078940000000
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem? In addition, i have many types of decimal values. Each one of them is in a different size. Is there's a generic size i can define?

Comment: How do you insert the values?

Comment: With `import` command from external file.

Answer (score 0):

change your type from decimal to double

Comment: Why? This will lose the precision OP wanted, when he used `DECIMAL`.

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: I changed it and i got the value 0.229078940000000

Comment: He said, "he don't know how to define the data-type", so I assumed it doesn't make a difference. You can keep decimal and change the length for example to (30,15), than u will have the insert value as well.